# If $L$ splits $D=I\otimes N$ does $L$ split $I$ and $N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, brauer-group

Let $D$ be a central simple division algebra over the field $F$. Let $D\sim I\otimes N$ where $I$ and $N$ are division algebras in Br$(F)$ and $\sim$ is equivalence in Br$(F)$. I am interested in this question.

**If $L$ splits $D$ does $L$ split $I$ and $N$?**

I can't seem to find this in any of the literature. Every example I can think of holds true. Does anyone know of a proof, have a reference, or a counter example? Any of them would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly not:
 Take any non-trivial division algebra $I$ over $F$ and let $N=I^{opp}$.
Then $F\sim I\otimes_F N$ is trivial in $Br(F)$ hence is split by $F$.
However neither $I$ nor $N$ is split by $F$.

Comment: Of course that's why it wasn't in the text.